# Survey tool with clickable version of the "Geneva emotion wheel"

Tags: emotion, survey

For my master thesis i would like to make a survey on user emotions on using a web user interface. The proband should write down his emotions using the "Geneva emotion wheel". (More information here: http://www.affective-sciences.org/gew).

Now i would like to know if there are any survey tools out there which offer this GEW as a clickable version. Or is it somewhere availlable as a "widget" which i can add then to my self created online survey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up a SVG version connected to a hidden html form. It's not perfect, but it may be useful anyway. You can find it [here](http://damien.lockner.fr/ressources/).

Note that a sufficient screen resolution is required.

Please send me feedbacks if you use it so that I can improve it.

Comment: Great work, which version of the wheel did you adapt? Maybe I will use the version 3 of the wheel in my surveys: http://www.affective-sciences.org/system/files/webpage/GEW_English_05042013.docx

Comment: ... or other question, why does your wheel have 7 gradiations of an emotion and the version 3 of the wheel does only have 5? What is the difference for the results?

Comment: Good question :) Indeed I did it years ago, and I couldn't find back the reason, nor a 7 gradations version in my sources. I guess I'll craft a 5-scales version (which, by the way, would be more usable)

Comment: In the meantime i finished my master thesis and i created a new version of your emotion wheel. You can find the new version here: https://bitbucket.org/manpil/masterthesiscoloursemotions